# How to resize SE80 Input Field area by default?

Tags: abap

I want to enlarge this input field by default. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's more a bug than a feature of course. You should see this at worst (ABAP 7.57 + setting to use old UI Web-based input controls + SAP GUI 7.70):
[image: SE80]

You seem to use an old version and probably some of the patches released by SAP could fix your issue. Unfortunately I can't paste the content as the access is reserved to licensed customers. If you don't have access, the issue concerns the handling of Windows DPI scaling, SAP GUI Windows Registry, old SAP GUI version, so maybe you can install the latest SAP GUI version (reserved to licensed customers).

- [2106323 - SAP GUI for Windows: DPI scaling of Windows will be supported](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2106323/E)
- [2161108 - Improvement of SE80 display for high DPI settings](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2161108/E)
- [2216308 - Usability problems in SE80 with SAP GUI 7.40](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2216308/E)

PS: another display bug in SE80 is about the small/frozen width of the left panel, whose fix is mentioned in the SAP note [2527919 - SE80 -Not able to resize the Browser width in Object navigator](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2527919/E) which implies a manual recovery action, which is described in SAP forums too.

Comment: Thank you Rossi. How did i not think of that... I guess trying to get used to that theme must have scared me.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you cannot do it. This GUI program is relative old and there are not too many interface settings.

Comment: Concerning "this GUI program is relatively old", it has appeared in 1999 ([release 4.6 - "enjoySAP"](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/09/01/evolution-of-abap/)). Nowadays, the ABAP developers use the modern and more productive [ADT plugin of Eclipse](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/09/12/happy-10th-anniversary-to-the-abap-development-tools-in-eclipse/).